Azure DevOps Pipeline behaves inconsistent, for reruns
we have an inconsistent behavior for azure pipeline runs/reruns.
Situation:
We have one package in the azure artifact registry, we can import it locally and use it in a normal way.(Let's assume for this question it is working as expected). Now we want to use that package in a second repository, within the CICD pipeline.
Our CICD pipeline is a classic azure yaml pipeline and makes multiple checks based on python dependencies. One of those is the before mentioned package. Since we use poetry but want to use requirements.txt for installation we do an intermediate step in which we poetry exports to a requirements.txt. After that the pipeline tries to install these dependencies.
This is our bash script in the pipeline:
- bash: pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt  --extra-index-url ${{ parameters.EXTRA_INDEX_URL }}
  condition: ne('${{ parameters.EXTRA_INDEX_URL }}', '')
  displayName: Install dependencies with extra-index-url

The extra index-url is supplied via pipeline.
The error that comes up in the failed pipeline is this one:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement package_name==0.1.4 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for package_name==0.1.4

So far so good, an error that may be expected due to different problems(although we have no solution, at the moment).
But here is the weird part, my colleague reran the failed jobs, which includes this one, just a few moments later. And now all of a sudden it works.

Collecting package_name==0.1.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 34))
Downloading https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/company/6a6a47aa-a6ae-48cf-abc7-e26c12d6f4ab/_packaging/a19cbe6e-aad3-4b9c-857a-786e475efddc/pypi/download/feed-name/0.1.4/package_name-0.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (7.4 kB)

No Errors nothing. How does this happen? We did not change the code in any way. May this be a caching issue? We are not using any cache task in azure devops.
Does anyone have a good way to start debugging?
Thank you in advance, if you new more specifics feel free to ask.
Update:
The number of retries it needs is not consistent either, it's not like one rerun always fixes it.
As additional information, we are using a lot of shared agents in our organization, currently around 30 agents. The two runs actually happened on different agents.The agents are microsoft hosted. But all agents should behave in the same manner, I assumed.

How often do these errors occur? It might have been a temporary networking issue. Also, outages might happen from time to time: https://status.dev.azure.com/_history

Also, consider configuring Automatic retries for a task - it might help to mitigate these issues.

Are you using self-hosted agent or Microsoft-hosted agent? If it's self-hosted, are the two builds(failed and successful) using same agent? Looks like a network problem.

@Code_beginner, compare the Microsoft-hosted agent between two builds, are their name started differently? such as fv- started or win started? Since the package with version 0.1.4 is ready to use before your pipeline, and it's consistently failed with Microsoft-hosted agent, it's recommended to try with a self-hosted agent, check if it will be stable.

@Code_beginner, may i know how is it going? Is it stable on self-hosted agent?

Hey @wadezhou-MSFT,
both times the host agent names are prefixed with fv-. I am unable to use self-hosted agents as I am not a poweruser but just a user of my companies internal service. Sadly.

Thanks for the update. If self-hosted agent is not available, you could consider to add more retry times with parameter retryCountOnTaskFailure for the bash task. If it doesn't mitigate, as it's Microsoft-hosted agent, you could need to raise a support ticket from azure to get help.

Thank you I will try that out, hope it mitigates the problem.
